# Definir página personalizada de erro 403

Tags: apache, htaccess

Tenho o seguinte trecho em meu arquivo `.htaccess`:

```htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
</IfModule>


# Bloqueia todos os arquivos PHP, com exceção do index.
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>

# Bloqueia a listagem de diretórios.
Options All -Indexes
```

Ele funciona corretamente, mas quando ele bloqueia a listagem de diretórios, ou arquivos php, ele cria um erro 403 que fica fora do layout default.

### Pergunta

Como posso "encaminhar" esses erros 403 para o arquivo `index.php`?

Eu tentei acrescentar o código:

```htaccess
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
```

mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme sua documentação, a diretiva [`ErrorDocument`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) do apache é bem flexível e possui 4 formas de redirecionar e apresentar uma mensagem de erro. A saber:

1. Exibir uma mensagem fixa simples (*hardcoded*)
2. Exibir uma mensagem personalizada
3. Redirecionar internamente para uma página local manipular o erro ou problema
4. Redirecionar para um endereço externo manipular o erro ou problema

A primeira opção consiste na página de erro padrão.

Já a mensagem personalizada consiste em definir um texto a ser exibido e pode ser configurada da seguinte forma:

```htaccess
ErrorDocument 403 "Sorry can't allow you access today"
```

A terceira opção, que é o caso da pergunta, permite redirecionar para uma página no sistemas de arquivos local. Note que o caminho deve ser uma URL relativa em relação ao `DocumentRoot` e ***deve*** iniciar com uma barra `/`.

```htaccess
ErrorDocument 404 /cgi-bin/bad_urls.pl
ErrorDocument 401 /subscription_info.html
```

A última opção é redirecionar para uma URL externa, cujo exemplo é:

```htaccess
ErrorDocument 500 http://foo.example.com/cgi-bin/tester
```

Comment: O problema é que o `index.php` não estava no `DocumentRoot`. Adicionei o caminho correto, resolvido.

Answer (score 5):

#### Para os desavisados (como eu): certifique-se de que o seu `.htaccess` está sendo interpretado.

- Experimente colocar uma linha inválida em qualquer lugar do `.htaccess` e veja se recebe um **Internal Server Error** no navegador. Senão, seu arquivo está sendo ignorado.
- Na configuração do `VirtualHost`, note que a opção `AllowOverride None` faz com que o `.htaccess` seja ignorado pelo Apache. Então revise a configuração do `VirtualHost` e coloque `AllowOverride All`. Por exemplo, em `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`:

```htaccess
<VirtualHost *:80>
# ...
    <Directory /var/www/pasta-do-meu-projeto/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            # AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
# ...
</VirtualHost>
```

- Lembre-se de reiniciar o Apache após modificar isto :)

  `$ sudo service apache2 restart`
- Verifique a permissão do arquivo. Já vi muita gente indicando `644`;

  `$ chmod 644 /var/www/pasta-do-meu-projeto/.htaccess`
- Só pra constar, não é necessário reiniciar o Apache para ver as modificações do `.htaccess` (esta é a idéia do `.htaccess` hehe)

#### Respondendo sua pergunta

**Mensagem de erro simples.** Inseri a linha a seguir no meu `.htaccess`:

```htaccess
ErrorDocument 403 "Acesso negado!"
```

Criei uma pasta vazia, tentei acessá-la e recebi a mensagem de erro esperada.

**Página com mensagem de erro.** Inseri a linha a seguir no meu `.htaccess`.

```htaccess
ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost/pasta-do-meu-projeto/403.html
```

Criei uma pasta vazia, tentei acessá-la e vi a página com erro esperada.

#### Ainda não resolvido

Por algum motivo, para o erro `403`, o arquivo local não funciona.

```htaccess
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
```

Criei uma pasta vazia, tentei acessá-la e recebi a seguinte mensagem do apache:

> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

#### Algumas referências (todas em inglês):

- ["Servidor Apache Ignora .htaccess"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210820/apache-server-ignores-htaccess);
- [".htaccess está sendo ignorado pelo Apache"](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1506129);
- [Documentação oficial do AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride)
- [Criando Mensagens de Erro Personalizadas no Apache](http://www.4webhelp.net/tutorials/misc/errors.php)
- [Documentação oficial do ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument)
- [Para para o erro 404 não está funcionando com meu .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639561/404-not-found-page-not-working-with-my-htaccess)

#### ATUALIZAÇÃO EM 17/01/2014, 13:53

Testei novamente a configuração abaixo e funcionou sem problemas:

```htaccess
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
```

NOTA: Como base, eu utilizei exatamente o mesmo `.htaccess` que você publicou.

Answer (score 4):

Basta passar o caminha do arquivo:

```htaccess
ErrorDocument 403 /dir/file.html
```

Outra referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703540/custom-error-403-page-php

Answer (score -1):

No meu caso não tinha ficado claro que o diretório que contém as novas páginas de erro fica sempre abaixo do principal.
Por exemplo, no caso do Apache o diretório fica abaixo de [ /public_html ]. O diretório [ dir ] da resposta 4 fica embaixo deste. Aí, qualquer .htaccess em qualquer pasta do site vai estar automaticamente referenciando este [ dir ] que está sob o [ /public_html ].
Um **engano muito comum** é criar um diretório de páginas de erros sob uma pasta que contenha conteúdo novo ( por exemplo, /public_html/wordpress/dir). Na verdade é na pasta raiz !

Comment: você utilizou a opção de enviar uma resposta, no entanto parece que sua intensão foi apenas comentar sobre experiência com este mesmo problema. Nesse caso considere adicionar um Comentário ao invés de uma Resposta.