# É possível pegar o Numero de Erro retornado pela Página

Tags: apache, htaccess, http

Criei uma página (sequindo o ensinado nesta [pagina](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2108/definir-p%C3%A1gina-personalizada-de-erro-403) ) de erro para o Erro 404, porém desta forma teria de fazer uma página de erro para cada Status HTTP, então gostária de fazer uma gnerica onde fosse possivel pegar o possivel erro do header http e criar com base no erro a página de erro, ai quando se fosse definir as paginas de erro no apache ficaria desta forma:

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost/pasta-do-meu-projeto/erro.html
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/pasta-do-meu-projeto/erro.html
ErrorDocument 501 http://localhost/pasta-do-meu-projeto/erro.html
```

Comment: Ricardo, descobri o motivo da URL redirecionar em alguns casos e em outros não, editei a resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se for PHP, pode tentar isto:

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost/pasta-do-meu-projeto/erro.php?status=403
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/pasta-do-meu-projeto/erro.php?status=404
ErrorDocument 501 http://localhost/pasta-do-meu-projeto/erro.php?status=501
```

E o PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['status'])) {
    echo $_GET['status'];
}
```

### Redirecionamento vs mod_rewrite

Se você quer não quer que a URL mude ao atingir uma página de erro, mas mesmo assim ocorra o redirecionamento, você deve usar o `RewriteCond` combinado com o `RewriteRule`, ficaria algo como:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /up/erro.php?status=404 [L]
```

Porém, se você quer que a url fique algo como `http://localhost/erro.php?status=404`, então não use-o, use apenas o `ErrorDocument`.

### Reescrita sem mod_rewrite

Ao fazer os alguns testes notei que

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/pasta-do-meu-projeto/erro.php?status=404
```

é diferente de

```
ErrorDocument 404 /pasta-do-meu-projeto/erro.php?status=404
```

Quando usamos o primeiro modo, o Apache não pode detectar ao certo se é um subdomínio, ou outro domínio ou o mesmo domínio, então não acontece acaba que redirecionando para a outra página, note também que não é possível pegar a variável `REDIRECT_STATUS`.

Porém ser usarmos o segundo modo com o caminho começando por `/` o redirecionamento é "interno", ou seja a página não redireciona, mas a resposta vem de outro local, o que nos permite acesso as variáveis como `REDIRECT_STATUS`, note que não é necessário o `mod_rewrite` habilitado.

### Atualização

Se estiver usando o PHP5.4+ você pode usar a função [`http_response_code`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.http-response-code.php)

Então o `ErrorDocument` não vai precisar do `?status=`

**Relatado:** [Pegar http status em versões do PHP inferiores ao 5.4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66515/3635)

Comment: .@GuilhermeNascimento obrigado por descobrir era justamente a segunda forma que estava usando, se pudesse dava upvote novamente em sua resposta.

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Por nada, acredita que eu fui criar a minha url-reescrita e comecei a apanhar, kkkk, agora já consegui descobrir várias coisas, só to com dificuldade em fazer o mesmo efeito no Nignix e no Lighttpd (servidores tipo apache), se eu conseguir tudo posto aqui pra compartilhar com o pessoal.