# Alternativa ao http_response_code em versões inferiores ao php5.4

Tags: php, http-status

É possível pegar o estado do HTTP em versões anteriores ao *PHP 5.4* ([`http_status_code`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) é suportado apenas no PHP5.4+)?

Eu estou criando um sistema de páginas de erros customizadas, não vai ser um sistema para um projeto especifico, porém por questão de compatibilidade eu gostaria de saber se é possível detectar o estado do PHP sem usar [`http_response_code`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php).

Preciso que seja independente do tipo de servidor, pois o script pode rodar em Apache, Nginx e Lighttpd.

Isto é possível? Tentei `$GLOBALS` e `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']`, porém no caso deste último, ele só funciona no Apache, no php-fpm só pego status `200`.

Comment: Já considerou usar a [função `curl_getinfo`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-getinfo.php) usando como argumento `CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE`? ela está disponível desde o  PHP *4.0.4*. Na tua primeira frase tem uma *afirmação* que contradiz o título. =)

Comment: @qmechanik Eu já havia visto isto, mas o problema é que ele só pega o status se setar primeiro, ou seja só funciona se você fizer isto: `<?php http_response_code(404); echo http_response_code();`. Isto não funciona `<?php echo http_response_code();`

Comment: @qmechanik Acho que tive uma ideia, vou criar um falso "location" e setar uma variavel de ambiente ENV com o código de http status.

Comment: Guilherme, teve algum sucesso? sobre a ideia do cURL, você poderia usar o `CURLOPT_NOBODY` para requisitar somente o cabeçalho *http* e não o conteúdo todo, assim irá diminuir o tempo para obter a resposta.

Comment: @qmechanik Obrigado pelo apoio e interesse, acredito que eu tenha conseguido o mais próximo possível de um resultado usável. Tiver alguma sugestão critica, é sempre bem-vindo :)

Comment: Não bastaria `header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');` pra simplificar?

Comment: @Bacco `http_response_code` pega ou define o código, no caso eu queria uma alternativa que fizesse ambos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que funcione em anteriores ao 5.4, como php5.3 e php5.3, pode-se criar urls "reservadas" usando `ErrorDocument` (apache, veja as alternativas pra outros servidores abaixo), usando por exemplo:

### .htacces (apache)

```
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php/RESERVED.HTTP-STATUS-403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php/RESERVED.HTTP-STATUS-404.html
```

### nginx

```
error_page 404 /RESERVED.HTTP-STATUS-404.html;
error_page 403 /RESERVED.HTTP-STATUS-403.html;

location ~ ^/RESERVED\.HTTP\-STATUS\-(403|404)\.html$ {
    rewrite ^/RESERVED\.HTTP\-STATUS\-(403|404)\.html$ /index.php$0 last;
}
```

### IIS

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="403" />
    <remove statusCode="404" />
    <error statusCode="403" path="/index.php/RESERVED.HTTP-STATUS-403.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="/index.php/RESERVED.HTTP-STATUS-501.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

### PHP

O arquivo deve conter este código:

```
/*Verifica se a função não esta disponível (versões anteriores ao php5.4)*/
if (false === function_exists('http_response_code')) {
    /*Fallback para versões mais antigas que o PHP5.4*/
    function http_response_code($code = null)
    {
        static $currentStatus;

        if ($code === null) {
            if ($currentStatus !== null) {
                return $currentStatus;
            }

            $currentStatus = 200;

            if (empty($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) === false &&
                preg_match('#/RESERVED\.HTTP\-STATUS\-(\d{3})\.html$#', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $match) > 0)
            {
                $currentStatus = (int) $match[1];
            }
        } elseif (is_int($code) && headers_sent() === false) {
            header('X-PHP-Response-Code: ' . $code, true, $code);
            $currentStatus = $code;
        }

        return $currentStatus;
    }
}
```

> Note que a função sempre irá disparar para o index.php, mas você pode trocar por error.php ou ao seu gosto.