# Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_response_code() php 5.2

Tags: php, http, funções

Peguei um script (Java android e php) de um livro que estou estudando, que simplesmente pega uma foto enviada do android e salva em uma pasta no meu servidor.

A aplicação android rodou sem nenhum erro, mas acabei me deparando com um erro no arquivo em php:

```
if ($_FILES["arquivo"]["error"] > 0) {
    // Bad Request
    http_response_code(400);
} else {
    $arquivo_destino = "imagens/" . $_POST["titulo"] . ".jpg";
    if (file_exists($arquivo_destino)) {
        http_response_code(501);
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file(
          $_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"],
          $arquivo_destino
      );
      http_response_code(200);
    }
}
```

O erro acontece na função `http_response_code(400)`, pesquisando na net li algo dizendo que esta função só funciona no php 5.4 ou maior (não tenho certeza se isso é verdade), então queria saber se tem alguma função alternativa para a minha versão do php 5.2.17.

Pra quem não entendou o que estou tentando fazer, estou enviando uma foto pelo android e retornando um código http de acordo com o que acontecer lá no servidor no arquivo php (se houver um erro com o arquivo retorna 400, se já existir um arquivo com o mesmo nome retorna 501, e se ocorrer tudo bem retorna 200).

Comment: Sei que esta apenas estudando, mas use sempre a versão mais nova do PHP. Essa dica vale ouro http://br.phptherightway.com/

Comment: Estou usando o servidor da locaweb do meu trabalho e nela parece que só tem o php 5.2.17.

Comment: Segue [Alternativa ao http_response_code em versões do PHP inferiores ao 5.4](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66515/3635)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque o uso da função [http_response_code()](http://php.net/http_response_code) pela função [header()](http://php.net/header), escrevendo os cabeçalhos diretamente:

```
if ($_FILES["arquivo"]["error"] > 0) {
    // Bad Request
    //http_response_code(400);
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Page not found');
} else {
    $arquivo_destino = "imagens/" . $_POST["titulo"] . ".jpg";

    if (file_exists($arquivo_destino)) {
        //http_response_code(501);
        header('HTTP/1.0 500');
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file(
            $_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"],
            $arquivo_destino
        );
        //http_response_code(200);
        header('HTTP/1.0 200');
    }
}
```

Para qualquer função PHP, quando precisar entender melhor sobre a função, apenas digite no seu browser: `http://php.net/NOME-DA-FUNÇÃO`. Exemplo: `http://php.net/http_response_code`.

Sobre o código que postou, evitarei discutir se o que está fazendo é certo ou erro. Mas recomendo não fazer isso. De qualquer forma, faça como achar melhor.

Comment: Te dei um ponto a mais de resposta util pois funcionou uma vez e agora está acontecendo coisas absurdas aqui.

Comment: No meu servidor tenho dois arquivos php, o upload_foto.php e o webservicesistema.php. O primeiro o codigo esta logo acima e o segundo, tem apenas um comando mysql que retorna um numero de acordo com a pesquisa.

Comment: Por exemplo se o usuario existir retorna 1,  se houver erro retorna 2, e se estiver tudo ok ele retorna os dados do usuario em formato json.

Comment: e qual a correlação disso com o status http?

Comment: estou usando o plugin PostMan do chrome para testes (ja uso ele faz tempo) e quando mando enviar uma foto para esse upload_foto.php ele dá o seguinte erro: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at upload_foto.php:1) in upload_foto.php on line 22

Comment: linha 22: header('HTTP/1.0 200');

Comment: E quando mando a foto para o arquivo webservicesistema.php ele salva a foto normal na pasta do servidor!!!!!

Comment: aí você já tem uma nova pergunta. Não faça múltiplas questões numa só. Sobre o erro do header, a própria mensagem de erro já diz o problema.

Comment: Desculpa é que eu fiquei confuso com essa situação

Comment: Mas voltando a pergunta então não tem como alterar o codigo http no header? Sua dunção funcionou uma vez e dai na segunda vez apareceu isso

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo a função `header()` do @Daniel Omine consegui fazer funcionar uma vez o upload da foto, mas daí me deparei com o erro:

`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at .../upload_foto.php:1) in .../upload_foto.php`

Então pesquisando encontrei uma resposta aqui no stack do @Bruno Augusto, que traduziu de um amigo dele de um outro fórum.
Olhando resposta dele (que vocês podem dar uma olhada aqui [Erro - Cannot modify header information](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-cannot-modify-header-information)) procurei um dos erros no meu código, que era ver se não tinha nenhum espaço em branco antes da tag de abertura `?php` e não tinha, mas pesquisando mais um pouco encontrei algo sobre alguns 'caracteres invisíveis' que podem ser gerados ao salvar os arquivos em alguns editores, e procurando como remover esses caracteres encontrei o programa HXD que pode ser baixado no link http://mh-nexus.de/downloads/HxDSetupPTB.zip .
O programa é bem leve e simples de usar, instale ele e abra o arquivo que está dando erro, a tela dele vai estar parecida com isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa imagem da pra ver que antes da tag de abertura `?php` existe outros caracteres(no meu caso eram outros caracteres diferentes) que não aparecem nos editores normais, voce só precisa removê-los e salvar o seu arquivo, simples assim.
Mas como saber se é esse mesmo o meu erro?
Simples, no meu caso o navegador dizia que o erro ocorria na linha 22. Mas não era realmente essa linha que dava o erro, essa linha apenas tentava executar a função `Header()`, a linha real do erro está sendo mostrada na parte entre parenteses `(output started at .../upload_foto.php:1)` no caso na linha 1, mas nessa linha só tinha a tag de abertura `?php`, então foi aí que eu percebi que tinha que ter algo 'escondido' ali.